# How to remove mesh from fluid

Tags: mesh, particles, fluid-simulation

[image]

I want it to be seen completely as a particle, but there's even a white mesh.
How to get rid of that white wave from the setup?
[image]

Comment: I don't know why you accepted the answer since this could not be the solution. Your question is lacking a lot of information - is that white "wave" the initial _Flow_ object or is it the resulting fluid mesh of the domain? For the latter, see my answer. For the _Flow_ object: just disable visibility in render and/or viewport if you don't want to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fluid simulation is supposed to be creating a fluid mesh which can be rendered afterwards - this will be showing in renders using the material which is on the domain object. And if there is no material, it will show the default (almost) white surface.

If you do not want to display the fluid mesh (to show particles like in your example) you could disable *Mesh* in the domain settings - but then the complete bounding box of the domain will be shown with whatever material you put on it. But disabling it will save you simulation time if you really do not need the mesh.

So to get rid of the domain in render, you have to give it a material with a simple *Transparent BSDF* set to fully white, which makes it completely invisible for the camera.

Fluid domain with *Mesh* enabled and no (or default) material:

[image: domain with mesh]

Fluid domain with *Mesh* disabled (no matter if it was simulated or not) shows domain's bounding box in render:

[image: domain bounding box]

Fluid domain with a completely transparent (= invisible) material - no matter if *Mesh* is enabled or disabled:

[image: transparent domain]

Comment: Oh, it must have been checked by mistake
As you said, I disabled the mesh and pressed bake and it worked! 
There was a misunderstanding because I am not good at English, but thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I think you just untick this mesh box in the domain if I am reading this correctly.

[image: This box is in the domain, you can search for 'mesh' to help find it.]

Comment: Actually when you disable _Mesh_ in the domain, the domain will be rendered as its complete bounding box which surely is not desired here. I do not know why this is the accepted answer though... even my answer will not help as I just realized, because I think what is rendered white there in the question is the _Flow_ object which initiated the fluid, not the domain/fluid mesh...